# web audio check if audio source is valid

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I wonder if there is any way to check if the source I get is valid or leads to nothing.

I get a name from the database but I have no idea if this is stored as an mp3 or a wav or anything else. So I need a way so if I put the name after my path of where my audio files are stored, I can check if I have to add .mp3 or .wav behind it.

I'm not using a html5 audio tag though!

This is a snippet of code i'm using

```
loadTracks = function(title,tracksrc) {
    sources.push({name: title, src: 'http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a12_web02/Katrijne/uPlay2audio/audio/tracks/' + tracksrc + '.mp3'}); 
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code snippets you can share?

Comment: @OskarEriksson Is this enough?

Comment: Your only option would be to perform an XHR `HEAD` request and then check the `Content-Type` response header. Of course this is dependent on the server returning the correct MIME type in the response.